# Android automatically download and install apk

Tags: java, android

we have our android application which is running in kiosk mode. We would like to have feature to automatically check for updates, install those updates and run application again. 
We can use some android service for that (actually, that's preferable way).

Do anybody has idea how we can accomplish that?

Thank you.

Comment: Stock Android does not allow this. However if you are changing the firmware for your kiosk you could conceivably add such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When the user has activated the auto update option in Play Store, then your update will automatically installed once the user has Wifi. If the user hasn't set this option you can do nothing about that.

You can ping your API every time your app starts, and your API has to tell you whether there is a new version. With this information you can display a popup to the user which forwards him to your PlayStore entry. But the user must select to update your app, you can not automate this process.

What you could do: If you write an HTML5 app, or you have a WebView which loads content from the network, then you can do your magic updates by simple updating the sources on server side.